# A true read-only bash?

Tags: linux, bash, ssh, shell, read-only

I've been looking for a true read-only version bash that we can provide to our auditors for view only permission in the Linux system. Our OS is CentOS 7 to be more specific.

We want to disallow user from using any directives such as ">" "<" "&", disallow user from executing any binaries except the ones in an allow list, such as "ls" "cd" "cat" "tail" "head" "less" only those read-only commands in an extremely short list.

rbash won't work for us, because it disables "cd" command by default, and there's no way around that.

I've also looked at the alias approach, but it requires rbash to work in combination.

ssh "only" approach won't work because our user needs to be able to "login" into the system and does auditing.

ssh chroot won't work because we need to allow auditor to view the actual user's home dir

lshell might be a solution but their website looks a bit out-dated, not sure if it is reliable.

Can someone advise if there's any other alternatives?

Comment: You might want to ask on [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/)

Comment: Could you use a chroot environment with the actual directories that they need to access mounted read-only within the environment?

Comment: @Kenster chroot + mount is a good idea, let me try that. Thank you